# Sharing user session in a database stripes framework

Tags: session, stripes, data-persistence

I am using Stripes framework for my webapp. Currently we have a requirement to implement load-balancer. To manage the user session some how I have to store the session data and access it in multiple servers to avoid logging out of users.

I am new to all this. Is there any support comes from stripes that allows to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Stripes uses session support from the underlying Java EE container. And the Java EE container is where session clustering/replication/persistance is configured. Look at Tomcat/Jetty/JBoss/whatever container you're using documentation

Comment: Thanks for replying.. If I m using one server, it is possible for me to use session persistance across multiple deployment to handle the issue..But when load balancer re-routes to a different server, it doesn't have the user session details and assuming as new user. If it can be stored in DB and pulled for every request, it will solve the issue. I am using tomcat server here..

Comment: Then read its documentation about clustering: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html